# Change format of product attribute

Tags: ubercart

I have products with a few options.

- Option 1: Same price.
- Option 2: -50 cent ($9.50).
- Option 3: -$1 ($9).

Can I change the display so that it looks like this?

- Option 1:
- Option 2: ($0.50 off)
- Option 2: ($1.00 off)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In uc_attribute.module file comment out from line number 1360 (starts at if ($adjustment != 0) {) to 1363 and add the bellow code

```
if ($adjustment != 0) {
    //$display_price = $adjustment > 0 ? '+' : '-';

    //this variable is used to flag your custom discount on minus values 
    $set_discount = false;

    if($adjustment > 0){
        $display_price = '+';
    }else{
        $display_price = '(';
        $set_discount = true;
    }
    if($set_discount){
        $display_price .= uc_currency_format(abs($adjustment)). ' off)';
    }else{
        $display_price .= uc_currency_format(abs($adjustment));
    }
}
```